# Qt array QString

Tags: qt, qstring, qbytearray

I get result from db by selectall query and I want save result in array and send it by socket.

```
db.open();

QSqlQuery *selectall = new QSqlQuery(db);
selectall->prepare("select * from phone_table");
selectall->exec();
selectall->first();
QString result;
QByteArray arrayresult;
int index = 0;
while (selectall->next())
{
    index += 1;
    // qint16 id = selectall->value(0).toString();
    QString name_ = selectall->value(1).toString();
    QString surname = selectall->value(2).toString();
    QString phone_number = selectall->value(3).toString();
    result = "*"+ name_+"*"+surname+"*"+phone_number;
    arrayresult[index] = result;
}
```

I get this error binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [16]'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a QByteRef to a QString.

I think you may want a QList and to arrayresult.append(result).
Or else if you want one QByteArray with the concat of all results use arrayresult+= result.

Answer (score 0):

You may build the `QString` you want to initialize `QByteArray`. To then convert from `QString` to `QByteArray`, you can do

```
QByteArray array_ = string_.toLatin1();
```

if encoding is Latin1.

You may alternatively use append

```
QByteArray & QByteArray::append ( const QString & str )
```

> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Appends the string str to this byte array. The Unicode data is
>   converted into 8-bit characters using QString::toAscii().
>
> If the QString contains non-ASCII Unicode characters, using this
>   function can lead to loss of information. You can disable this
>   function by defining QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII when you compile your
>   applications. You then need to call QString::toAscii() (or
>   QString::toLatin1() or QString::toUtf8() or QString::toLocal8Bit())
>   explicitly if you want to convert the data to const char *.

`append` is doing the same as `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with the [toLatin1()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) function of the `QString`.

```
// ...

QString result = QString( "*%1*%2*%3" ).arg( name_ )
                                       .arg( surname )
                                       .arg( phone_number );

QByteArray resultArray = result.toLatin1();
// Or ...
// QByteArray resultArray = result.toLocal8Bit();
// QByteArray resultArray = result.toUtf8();
```

And you shall use a `QList< QByteArray >` for containing the results, or you can just [`append`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#append) the last result item to your final result object.